# Why is GetProcessHeap returning a nonsense handle on Windows 10?

Tags: c#

I have built an application using C# with unsafe code and while it worked fine on Windows 7, when I tried to run the executable (copied the build directory onto a different machine: Windows 10) I get a nonsense handle returned from GetProcessHeap (negative numbers). The rest of the rest of the application works fine just the unsafe code and manual memory management is causing a problem all I suspect from the dodgy handle.

The source code:

```
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        static extern int GetProcessHeap();
        static int Handle=0;

        public void test()
        {
            Null_Value = go.go_get_null_flag();
            Handle = GetProcessHeap();
            MessageBox.Show(Handle.ToString());
        }
```

The code targets x64, was built using VS2013 (Windows 7) and .NET 4.5.

There seems little support out there any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A handle value should probably be an IntPtr not an int.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir you'd think so. But the docs state an int and trying with an IntPtr produces a compiler warning/error.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs

Comment: ReferenceSource shows them using it to return an `IntPtr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is you're on a 64-bit system, so your handle will be 64-bits, yet you're trying to store it into a 32-bit field.

Change your method declaration to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetProcessHeap();

static IntPtr Handle=0;
```

Then calling it:

```
Handle = GetProcessHeap();
```

Comment: Cheers Amy. I'm bloody stupid I didn't look at the bleeding obvious my "prototypes". D'oh.